# Дерево не удаляется

Tags: c++

```
void DeleteTree(Tree*root)
{

        while (root != NULL) {
            DeleteTree(root->left);
            DeleteTree(root->right);
            root = NULL;
            delete root;
        }
```

Comment: Агде само дерево?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на свои последние две строки. Вначале Вы зануляете указатель, а потом удаляете данные по нему, то есть, по null. По хорошему, их нужно переставить местами. Ну и while не нужен.

```
void DeleteTree(Tree*root)
{
    if(root != NULL) {
        DeleteTree(root->left);
        DeleteTree(root->right);
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: А while тут работает как обычный if.

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть так:

```
void DeleteTree(Tree*root)
{
    if (root != NULL) 
    {
       DeleteTree(root->left);
       DeleteTree(root->right);
       delete root;
    }
}
```

А вы сначал обнуляете root, а потом удаляете его.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, это очепятка?

```
root = NULL;
delete root;
```

И вы все же сначала удаляете `root` (освобождая память), а у потом обнуляете, а не пытаетесь удалять указатель `NULL`?